# How do retrieve all the data from a Data Extensions object without giving Properties field?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi

There is an DataExtension object "Profile". Since its custom created the end user who is working on SOAP API retrieval doesn't know the Columns/Attributes listed in there. So is there a way to retrieve all the attributes and its data from SOAP API
[image]

Current Problem

```
    <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[Profile]</ObjectType>
                    <Properties>Contact Id</Properties> ***Without Mentioning the Properties***
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: I don't think that you can do that retrieve without the property names. But, your client app could do a first soap action to retrieve the data extension fields, and with that result, then, query the records.

Comment: @JavierDeMauri, Can you point me to the request which needs to be made in order to retrieve the fields and also can the data extension objects be retrieved like the fields you mentioned ?

Comment: Sure, you can do a retrieve request to: DataExtensionField object. Use a simple filter to get your specific data extension's fields. "Name", "DefaultValue", "MaxLength", "IsRequired", "IsPrimaryKey", "FieldType" among others are properties you can retrieve from DataExtensionField.

Comment: @JavierDeMauri Can you add a small snippet which will help me out. I was receiving an error when I tried the following  
```           <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>DataExtensionField</ObjectType>
                        <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                            <Property>Name</Property>
                        </Filter>
            </RetrieveRequest>
```

Comment: Sure!, you can find a very good example from @AdamSpriggs here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56443/how-to-get-list-of-data-extension-fields-using-soap-api

Answer (score 0):

You could use the undocumented REST API endpoint to get the info you need. Do note that it is **undocumented** and so it is use at your own risk as it is not officially supported by SFMC.

```
GET /data/v1/customobjectdata/key/{{deKey}}/rowset
Host: {{subDomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{AuthToken}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

OR can also do via ID like `/data/v1/customobjectdata/{{deID}}/rowset`

Which gives a return like:

```
{
    "links": {
        "self": "/v1/customobjectdata/token/{{deID}}/rowset?$page=1"
    },
    "requestToken": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
    "tokenExpireDateUtc": "2020-08-14T14:34:48.28",
    "customObjectId": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
    "customObjectKey": "{{deKey}}",
    "pageSize": 2500,
    "page": 1,
    "count": 2,
    "items": [
        {
            "keys": {
                "subscriberkey": "subkey1"
            },
            "values": {
                "emailaddress": "myEmail@email.com",
                "firstname": "Gor",
                "lastname": "Tonington"
            }
        },
        {
            "keys": {
                "subscriberkey": "subkey2"
            },
            "values": {
                "emailaddress": "myEmail2@email.com",
                "firstname": "G",
                "lastname": "Tonington"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @Goronington Thanks for the Rest Endpoint. To add to your answer Is there any other endpoint wherein I can retrieve all the {DEid} or {DEkey}

Comment: only via the SOAP Object DataExtension. There is no REST endpoint to grab this info (or at least not one I am aware of that is public facing).

Comment: is it possible to retrieve `_CustomObjectKey` for rows with this endpoint? I tried to specify it `$fields` parameter but it didn't work